# Jest --runTestsByPath two or more different paths

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'm using the [jest cli](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli) to run my tests. Jest has a cli option called [`--runTestsByPath`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#runtestsbypath) that I'm using to specify where my tests are.

I have unit tests spread across my repository in different directories, but I want to run them all in one command. One option is to `&&` different jest commands:

```json
{
  "name": "node-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --runTestsByPath ./__tests__/tests/over/here/*_test.ts && jest --runTestsByPath ./tests/over/__tests__/here/*_test.ts",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "24.8.0",
    "ts-jest": "24.0.2",
    "ts-node": "8.3.0",
    "typescript": "2.9.2"
  }
}
```

But, I then lose the functionality like coverage that I get from running them all from 1 jest command.

I'm wondering, because it is not documented anywhere, or answered here on SO, how can I pass two or more different paths to `--runTestsByPath`?

Answer (score 3):

We can pass multiple paths to jests `--runTestsByPath` cli option:

```bash
jest --runTestsByPath ./__tests__/tests/over/here/*_test.ts ./tests/over/__tests__/here/*_test.ts
```